# Responsive image with a close button in corner

Tags: css

I need a Lightbox with a responsive image that has a close button in the top right corner of the image.

This works only in Safari:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.9);
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/1600x900" />
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in Chrome and Firefox the `height: fit-content` of `.inner` doesn't work.

Here is a [video demonstration](https://imgur.com/a/2yX8Dw8).

Comment: they do support fit-content and your .inner div fit its content. The code works.

Comment: @Mehdi No, the code doesn't work. Run the snippet in Chrome and Firefox in full screen. Resize the window vertically. The image doesn't scale, `fit-content` has no effect.

Comment: I did and it actualy does

Comment: @Mehdi I made a [screenshot for you](https://imgur.com/a/zJpWWs3)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.9);
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/1600x900" />
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use "100vh" instead of "100%" it will help

Comment: This is great, except it doesn't respect the vertical padding of the container.

Comment: I accepted your answer. The only thing I had to change to have horizontal and vertical space around the image was to remove the padding from the outer container, and to to use `calc` for the image size, eg: `max-width: calc(100vw - 50px)`